# React fetch data getting lost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, fetch-api

I have a component in which I fetch data based on an item ID that was clicked earlier. The fetch is successful and `console.log` shows the correct data, but the data gets lost with `this.setState`. I have `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` in the same component, not sure if this is okay or maybe these two are messing each other up?

Here is the code:

```
const teamAPI = 'http://localhost:8080/api/teams/'
const playerAPI = 'http://localhost:8080/api/playersByTeam/'
const matchAPI = 'http://localhost:8080/api/match/'

class View extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      playersData: [],
      update: [],
      team1: [],
      team2: [],
      matchData: [],
      testTeam: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.matchId !== this.props.matchId) {
      fetch(matchAPI + this.props.matchId)
      .then((matchResponse) => matchResponse.json())
      .then((matchfindresponse) => {
        console.log(matchfindresponse);
        this.setState({
          matchData:matchfindresponse,
          testTeam:matchfindresponse.team1.name,
        })
      })
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(teamAPI)
    .then((Response) => Response.json())
    .then((findresponse) => {
      console.log(findresponse)
      this.setState({
        data:findresponse,
        team1:findresponse[0].name,
        team2:findresponse[1].name,
      })
    })

    fetch(playerAPI + 82)
    .then(playerResponse => playerResponse.json())
    .then(players => {
      console.log(players)
      this.setState({
        playersData:players
      })
    })
  }
```

The first render also gives this warning:

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
>
> Please check the code for the View component.

Everything from `ComponentDidMount works` fine in render but `{this.state.matchData}` and `{this.state.testTeam}` from `componentDidUpdate` are empty.

Could the problem be that `ComponentDidMount` re-renders the component which causes the data from `ComponentDidUpdate` to be lost and if so, how could I fix this?

Tried `ComponentWillReceiveProps` like this but still no luck:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.matchId !== this.props.matchId) {
      fetch(matchAPI + newProps.matchId)
      .then((matchResponse) => matchResponse.json())
      .then((matchfindresponse) => {
        console.log(matchfindresponse.team1.name);
        console.log(this.props.matchId + ' ' + newProps.matchId);
        this.setState({
          matchData:matchfindresponse.team1.name,
        })
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: :o Sorry, maybe I worked on a too old version of React... Last time I used it, i'm pretty sure I had to merge like that! Removing it, sorry again... I'm gonna take a deeper look!

Comment: It looks like you should use `componentWillReceiveProps` and not `componentDidUpdate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your componentDidMount you should be using Promise.all. This isn't really your problem, but it does make more sense.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const promises = [
    fetch(teamAPI).then(resp => resp.json()),
    fetch(playerAPI + 82).then(resp => resp.json())
  ];
  Promise.all(promises).then(([teamData, playerData]) => {
   // you can use this.setState once here
  });
}
```

Looks like your componentDidUpdate should be a getDerivedStateFromProps in combination with componentDidUpdate (this is new to react 16.3 so if you are using an older version use the depreciated componentWillReceiveProps). Please see https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/issues/26. Notice too that now componentDidUpdate receives a third parameter from getDerivedStateFromProps. Please see https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html for more details.

EDIT: Just to add more details.
Your state object should just include other key like matchIdChanged.
Then

```
// in your state in your constructor add matchId and matchIdChanged then
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
 if (nextProps.matchId !== prevState.matchId) {
   return { matchIdChanged: true, matchId: nextProps.matchId }
 }
 return null;
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.matchIdChanged) {
    fetch(matchAPI + this.props.matchId)
      .then((matchResponse) => matchResponse.json())
      .then((matchfindresponse) => {
        console.log(matchfindresponse);
        this.setState({
          matchData:matchfindresponse,
          testTeam:matchfindresponse.team1.name,
          matchIdChanged: false // add this
        })
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried ComponentWillReceiveProps but the result is the same. I might have done something wrong though. See original post update to see what I did.

Comment: Unfortunately im on React version 16.2 so I am trying to work this with ComponentWillReceiveProps but thank you very much for pointers.

Comment: You can optionally upgrade to React 16.3. There are no breaking changes plus you get the new context API which is very nice to work with.

Comment: I updated to 16.3 and tried getDerivedStateFromProps and get this warning now: Warning: View: getDerivedStateFromProps() is defined as an instance method and will be ignored. Instead, declare it as a static method.

Comment: Just put static in front of it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Sorry for being a total pleb but now I get: Cannot read property 'props' of null

Comment: Sorry that was my fault. Thanks for letting me help. Please see my updated answer. This is what happens when you don't test your answers :)

Comment: Thanks, now it is doing two fetches inside componentDidUpdate though. First fetch is with the correct id but then it overwrites it instantly with undefined, probably because the state changes?

Comment: Are you constantly changing the matchId? Basically you're saying that your componentDidUpdate is running twice? Can you console.log(nextProps) inside getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: Yes, it is running twice. First log is with the correct ID and second with undefined. So I am guessing first time it runs correctly and second time because matchIdChanged gets changed back to false?

Comment: The id from nextprops is undefined. If that's the case then you need to look at the whatever is passing props to this component. What does the console.log on nextProps look like in the getDerivedStateFromProps ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using componentDidUpdate() lifecycle hook of react try using **getDerivedStateFromProps()** lifecycle function if you are using **react 16.3**, else try using **componentWillReceiveProps() for below versions**. In my opinion try to avoid the use of componentDidUpdate().

Plus error you are getting is because, setState() function is called, when your component somehow gets unmounted, there can be multiple reasons for this, most prominent being -

1. check the render function of this component, are you sending null or something, based on certain condition?
2. check the parent code of component, and see when is the component getting unmounted.

Or you can share these code, so that we might help you with this.

Plus try to **debug using ComponentWillUnmount()**, put console.log() in it and test it for more clarity.

Hope this helps, thanks